# how to read property file value in spring at runtime from input string

Tags: java, xml, spring, properties, spring-config

I am using Java+Spring+spring XML configuration in my project.

I would like to read one property value from the property file and set java value in spring configuration using input String value.

**MyClass.class**

```
private String tableDetails;
private String logpath;
```

**myTest.properties**

```
log_path=C:\test\app
table1_details=table1Name|table1Key|query1
table2_details=table2Name|table2Key|query2
table3_details=table3Name|table3Key|query3
```

**Spring_config.xml**

```
<bean id="myClass" class="com.test.MyClass">
        <property name="logpath" ref="${log_path}"/>
<property name="tableName" value="#{systemProperties['checker.table']}"/>        
        <property name="tabledetails" value="${#{systemProperties['checker.table']}}"/>
```

**suppose checker.table = table1_details then**

```
<!--working-->
<property name="tableDetails" value="${table1_details}"/> 
<!--not working-->
<property name="tableDetails" value="${#{systemProperties['checker.table']}}"/>
```

So the requirement is that I have property name in systemProperties['checker.table'] which I am not able to use in value field to read the property details of table1_details and set the tableDetails in MyClass?

Answer (score 1):

In your java/pojo class to take value from properties file write -

```
@value("${table1_details}")
String tableDetails;

@value("${log_path}")
String logpath;
```

You also have to mention your properties file in xml -

```
<context:place-holder location="classpath*:myTest.properties">
```

And to read value of POJO in xml file call get method like -

```
<bean id="abc" class = "qwe.ert.MyClass"/> 
<bean id="xyz" class= "qwe.ert.NewClass">
    <property name="tableDetails" value="#{abc.getTableDetails()}">
    <property name="log" value="#{abc.getLogPath()}">
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Annotate your class with

```
@PropertySource("sourceOfProperty")
```

inject value to field

```
@Value(${property})
```

You can also access property from Environment

```
env.getProperty("property")
```